# Matrix Multiplication with Dynamically Allocated Arrays; Result Incorrect

Tags: c++

I have been trying to debug this code for awhile, but I'm not sure how to actually access values in my IDE when they are located in dynamically allocated memory. This program is supposed to initialize two matrices based on the user's input and then multiply them together, if possible.

I have found a few mistakes and corrected them, but I'm not sure what is causing this issue.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef int* IntArrayPtr;

int main() {
    int r1, c1, r2, c2;
    do {
        //GET DIMENSIONS OF MATRICIES
        cout << "Welcome! This program takes two matricies and multiplies them together.\n"
            << "Enter the number of rows and number of columns for Matrix 1: ";
        cin >> r1 >> c1;
        cout << "Enter the number of rows and number of columns for Matrix 2: ";
        cin >> r2 >> c2;

        //DETECT IF MULTIPLICATION CAN HAPPEN
        if (r1 != c2) {
            cout << "Error: matricies cannot be multiplied. Please enter a new set.\n";
        }
    } while (r1 != c2); //have the user enter again if the rows and columns don't match
    cout << endl;

    //INTIALIZE MATRICIES USING DYNAMIC ARRAYS
    //intialize MATRIX 1
    IntArrayPtr *a = new IntArrayPtr[r1];
    cout << "For MATRIX 1: Enter the contained values. Press enter after each entry.\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
        a[i] = new int[c1]; //init columns for each row
        cout << "ROW" << i + 1 << "\n";
        for (int j = 0; j < c1; j++) {
            cin >> a[i][j]; //fill columns of rows
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    //intialize MATRIX 2
    IntArrayPtr *b = new IntArrayPtr[r2];   //init rows
    cout << "For MATRIX 2: Enter the contained values. Press enter after each entry.\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < r2; i++) {
        b[i] = new int[c2]; //intialize columns
        cout << "ROW" << i + 1 << "\n";
        for (int j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
            cin >> b[i][j]; //fill columns of rows
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    //INITIALIZE MATRIX TO STORE RESULT IN
    //matrix will have the rows of the first and columns of the second, according to matrix multiplication
    IntArrayPtr *c = new IntArrayPtr[r1]; //init rows
    for (int i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
        c[i] = new int[c2]; //init columns
    }

    //MULTIPLY MATRICIES
    for (int i = 0; i < r1; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c2; ++j) {
            for (int k = 0; k < c1; ++k) {
                c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    //PRINT RESULT
    for (int i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
            cout << c[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    delete[] a; delete[] b; delete[] c;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The matrix should be the result of multiplication, but when I try to execute the program using small matricies (e.g. 3 x 2 times 2 x 3), the output spits out what seems to me to be garbage. I'm sure my mistake is silly, but help would be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Unrelated: The comments you have over each section in your one-and-only function (`main`) could be made into functions with names similar to what you write as comments. It helps debugging and re-using similar code pieces. You only need one piece of code to initialize matrices so a function named `initialize_matrix` would probably work.

Comment: `c[i][j] +=` is adding to `c[i][j]` but those values are never initialized.

Comment: should't c[i][j] be 0, if they are initialized with new?

Comment: @v78 no they will not

Comment: Obligatory comment about not using `new` and `delete`. If you need to allocate a dynamic array you should be using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. If you are dynamically creating single objects you should use [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) or [`std::make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) instead.

Comment: @v78 C++ will rarely zero your objects. Assume it won't unless you know for a fact it will. This is in accordance with the "don't pay for what you don't use" objective for C++'s design. Sometimes when you `new` something you will immediately assign it a meaningful value (like you do when you initialize your first two matrices). If `new` did the work of zeroing out your array, it would be lost work in those cases. You would be paying for zeroing that you don't need.

Comment: @v78 Regarding "_should't c[i][j] be 0, if they are initialized with new?_" - I feel I didn't answer it properly. `new` does **not** initialize, which was the whole point. It just allocates memory.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I was writing this specifically for a class whose instructions were to use this form of allocation. That is good information to know for general programming though; thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't initialize the matrix c properly. Try this

```
//INITIALIZE MATRIX TO STORE RESULT IN
//matrix will have the rows of the first and columns of the second, according to matrix multiplication
IntArrayPtr *c = new IntArrayPtr[r1]; //init rows
for (int i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
    c[i] = new int[c2]; //init columns
    for (int j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
        c[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```